# Removing vowels from a string unless the vowel starts the word using a for loop

Tags: java

I have to remove all vowels from a string using a for loop.

I have this declaration so I can just call VOWELS.

```
public static final String VOWELS = "aeiouAEIOU";
```

I'm just not sure how to return the string with no vowels in it but keep the vowel if starts the word.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static String stringCompress(String msg){

    String rtn = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < msg.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isWhitespace(i)){
            rtn += (char)(msg.charAt(i - 1);
        }
        else if(VOWELS.contains(msg.valueOf(i))){
            rtn += msg.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

but it's not returning what I need it to. its returning [be a r, if]

I am just really confused. Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 1):

> Removing vowels from a string unless the vowel starts the word using a for loop

You are making several mistakes.

- you don't want to use `valueOf`.  Use `charAt()`
- As easy way to determine start of word is to save the previous character for testing as a space. So initialize it to a space.
- then if the previous char was not a space (i.e. not start of word) and the current character is a vowel, ignore it.
- otherwise append it to the return string.
- continue until the loop is done (which should start at 0 and not 1).

```
String test = "Animal    Horse   Elephant Dog cat ";
System.out.println(stringCompress(test));
```

prints

```
Anml    Hrs   Elphnt Dg ct
```

- Use a `StringBuilder` to house the result
- `lastChar` is used to determine if it was preceded by a white space.

```
public static String stringCompress(String msg) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char lastChar = ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
        char c = msg.charAt(i);
        if (!VOWELS.contains(c+"")
                || Character.isWhitespace(lastChar)) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        lastChar = c;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using StringBuilder :

```
public static String stringCompress(String msg) {
    StringBuilder rtn = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(i) || !VOWELS.contains(msg.charAt(i) + "")) {
            rtn.append(msg.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return rtn.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, look at the `isWhitespace` line, maybe that is your problem:

```java
public static String stringCompress(String msg){

    String rtn = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < msg.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isWhitespace(msg.valueOf(i))){
            rtn += (char)(msg.charAt(i - 1);
        }
        else if(VOWELS.contains(msg.valueOf(i))){
            rtn += msg.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```